# Install alongside windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on my new laptop. The option mentioned in the install guide to "install alongside Windows" does, however, not appear in the install wizard. When I select "Something else" I am presented (as expected) with the disk manager.

My problem is that this laptop came with no less than 7 partitions! Windows is only aware of one 418GB partition. My question is this: How do I resize that windows partition to be as small as possible, create space to install Ubuntu, and use the rest as a shared NTFS partition. Ideally, I would like to put Win 7 on there as well, as I am not a great fan of Win 8.

I would be more than happy to live without Win 8 (If I can put 7 on). I am just apprehensive to completely format the drive and lose the recovery partition. I did make a recovery DVD and a recovery USB drive (which is about 14 GB big), though.

Any suggestions / help would be greatly appreciated!

To make it clear, i took some screenshots of the install wizard. Unfortunately, I cannot post images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the partition you want to resize and then click Change. This should enable you to resize the partition. You'll then be able to create additional partitions for Linux.

Note also that you'll need to set your [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) (ESP; your `/dev/sda2`) as an "EFI boot partition," and you'll need to set mount point(s) for all the Linux filesystem partition(s) you create. All of these things can be done from the dialog box that appears when you select a partition and click "Change."