# Issue with partitioned disk while trying to install ubuntu 13.10 along with Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I have an installed windows 8 OS on my C drive and looking forward to install Ubuntu 13.10 as a dual boot alongside Windows 8 OS. I have the following partition set up,
System reserved: 100 MB
C: 60 GB (NTFS)
D: 40 GB (NTFS)
E: 50 GB (NTFS)
Unallocated: 60 GB

I am trying to install ubuntu on the unallocated space but this is not shown while installing the Ubuntu. I don't know where to create partitions for the ubuntu installation. Can you please guide me here?
Thanks!

Comment: during the installation gparted application pups up.. there you set up you partition...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers on your question within forum. Like this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372012/install-alongside-windows-8) Windows 7, 8 are gpt disks commonly. Also read [HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) partition.

Comment: No there isn't. My issue is different from the one you have referred here. My issue is that unallocated space not being shown in the ubuntu installation. Only when i see that, i can create further partitions for ubuntu and complete installation. Hope I am clear.

Comment: how is it different? If you want to install Ubuntu on a GPT disk (you can check it via the `sudo parted -l` command), you will need either an EFI partition (if your BIOS is setup in EFI mode) or a BIOS-Boot partition (if your BIOS is setup in Legacy mode). Did you check it?

Comment: I am new to linux and I am not able to understand your post. What do you mean by GPT disk? I am running windows 8, will the command you have given work? How do I check the partition?

Comment: use the command in Terminal Ctrl+Alt+T `sudo fdisk -l` to see what partitions your system sees and check if it's gpt disk `sudo parted -l` for more details about Ubuntu partitions use the guide in my answer `HowTo`. Or upload screenshots from GParted.

Comment: also more than 4 separate partitions don't make sense in Ubuntu (4 is the maximum number of primary partitions you can create) - it's just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, unallocated would only show up if the section of HDD is not formatted at all. if they are seperate HDD's the contents of E: in the ubuntu istallation would most likely show up as:
/dev/sdc showing 110gb (NTFS)

if it is truly 'unallocated' then E: would show up as:
/dev/sdc1 50gb (NTFS) and 
/dev/sdc2 60gb (unallocated)

picking sdc as the HDD to install from even if all of it is formatted as NTFS will bring up the option of allocating a portion of it to ubuntu (EXT) + linux swap filesystems
though you must choose to install alongside windows.

you can setup the partitions manually also

remember that /dev/sda is usually what windows would call C:
/dev/sdb would be D:
/dev/sdc would be E:

sda1 would mean first partition of C:
sda2 would mean second partition of C: etc..

though if its one HDD setup in partitionss then
c: = sda1
d: = sda2
e: = sda3 etc

hope this explains a little more, when i first installed ubuntu the unix way of identifing partiotions and HDD's was sort of confusing